# Could not find "io.ktor:ktor-utils-cinterop-utils"

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, ktor-client

I am facing a issue when using Ktor in local where I am using ktor :ktor-client-okhttp version 2.0.0 and I am using a library where the library is using 1.5.3

Local gradle

```
      const val ktorCore = "$ktorGroup:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion"
      const val ktorJson = "$ktorGroup:ktor-client-json:$ktorVersion"
      const val ktorLogging = "$ktorGroup:ktor-client-logging:$ktorVersion"
```

Below is the error I am getting

`e: Could not find "io.ktor:ktor-utils-cinterop-utils" in [/Users/abc/Documents/def/kmp-working/cxyz-shared, /Users/abc/.konan/klib, /Users/abc/.konan/kotlin-native-prebuilt-macos-x86_64-1.6.10/klib/common, /Users/abc/.konan/kotlin-native-prebuilt-macos-x86_64-1.6.10/klib/platform/ios_arm64]`

I tried changing the local ktor version to 1.5.3 and it solved the issue , but downgrading the local won't be helping us.

Any suggestions would be greateful.

Comment: Are you using gradle as your build system? If so, do you specify this library in dependencies?

Comment: Yes I am using this in the android gradle project , yes I have specified the library in the dependencies

Comment: Can you try using the latest version of Ktor 2.3.1? And make sure that you use Kotlin 1.8.20 or later.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman are you saying that I should update my app gradle version from 2.0.0 to 2.3.1 . And As I mentioned above I can't update the library ktor version. And how updating kotlin 1.8.20 will help removing this error? What is the root cause of this isue?

Comment: The relevant issue is https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-5483, and it's fixed in Kotlin 1.8.20.